# Sqlalchemy Snowflake not closing connection after successfully retrieving results

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am connecting to [snowflake datawarehouse](https://www.snowflake.net/product/) from Python and I encounter a weird behavior. The Python program exits successfully if I retrieve fewer number of rows from SnowFlake but hangs in there in-definitely if I try to retrieve more than 200K rows. I am 100% sure that there are no issues with my machine because I am able to retrieve 5 to 10 million rows from other type of database systems such as Postgres.

My Python environment is Python 3.6 and I use the following version of the libraries -> SQLAlchemy 1.1.13, snowflake-connector-python 1.4.13, snowflake-sqlalchemy 1.0.7,

The following code prints the total number of rows and closes the connection.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

engine = create_engine(URL(
            account=xxxx,
            user=xxxxx,
            password=xxxxx,
            database=xxxxx,
            schema=xxxxxx,
            warehouse=xxxxx))

query = """SELECT * FROM db_name.schema_name.table_name LIMIT 1000"""

results = engine.execute(query)
print (results.rowcount)
engine.dispose()
```

The following code prints the total number of rows but the connection doesn't close, it just hangs in there until I manually kill the Python process.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

engine = create_engine(URL(
            account=xxxx,
            user=xxxxx,
            password=xxxxx,
            database=xxxxx,
            schema=xxxxxx,
            warehouse=xxxxx))

query = """SELECT * FROM db_name.schema_name.table_name LIMIT 500000"""

results = engine.execute(query)
print (results.rowcount)
engine.dispose()
```

I tried multiple different tables and I encounter the same issue with SnowFlake. Did anyone encounter similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the query status from UI? "History" page should include the query. If the warehouse is not ready, it may take a couple of minutes to start the query. (I guess that's very unlikely, though).

Try changing the connection to this:

```
connection = engine.connect()
results = connection.execute(query)
print (results.rowcount)
connection.close()
engine.dispose()
```

SQLAlchemy's dispose doesn't close the connection if the connection is not explicitly closed. I inquired before, but so far the workaround is just close the connection.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sqlalchemy/shige%7Csort:date/sqlalchemy/M7IIJkrlv0Q/HGaQLBFGAQAJ

Lastly, if the issue still persist, add the logger to top:

```
import logging

for logger_name in ['snowflake','botocore']:
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.FileHandler('log')
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(funcName)s() - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
    logger.addHandler(ch)
```

and collect log.

If the output is too long to fit into here, I can take it at the issue page at https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy.

Note I tried it myself but cannot reproduce the issue so far.

Comment: Hey Sig, thanks for your response. The problem still persists so I added an issue in GitHub - https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/37

Comment: Updated the doc. https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy#opening-and-closing-connection

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a with statement instead to make your connection

instead of this:

```
engine = create_engine(URL(account=xxxx,user=xxxxx,password=xxxxx,database=xxxxx,schema=xxxxxx,warehouse=xxxxx))
results = engine.execute(query)
```

do the following:

```
with create_engine(URL(account=xxxx,user=xxxxx,password=xxxxx,database=xxxxx,schema=xxxxxx,warehouse=xxxxx)) as engine:
    # do work
    results = engine.execute(query)
    ...
```

After the with .. the engine object should be automatically closed out.